# How to make lookup tables shared to multiple site with the same DB and every site can have a customized list of this lookup?

Tags: database, architecture

I want to having all common data (i.e. nationalities) identical in all site   (the main webmaster/administrator who should decide either to make a certain list global or not)
how to achieve this goal in the database design or in the system architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one master list and share them across applications, you can better do it in database. Create a nationality table. I would do it in database, load from it to the application and use it.

Comment: ok already we have this table in db and this db accessed by multiple sites , how the admin can add customized items and this site only can see it

Comment: In that case, you can have a column APP_ID and use it to filter for application wise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow - but couldn't you simply connect all your different sites to the same DB? Assuming that you're not using in-process databases, it should be fine.